# What are the best algorithms to predict a continuous target where I only have binary attributes?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, algorithms, continuous-data, dependent-variable

[image]

Hello, I am new to machine learning and have a project where the dataset consists of binary attributes and the target("Pawpularity") has a continuous value. I was wondering if you could advise me what are the best algorithms to use to train and try to predict this target?

Comment: How many rows does your dataset have?

Comment: Your outcome doesn't happen to be between 0 and 100 does it?  If so, do any observations score 0 or 100 exactly?

Comment: @MichaelM 9912 rows.

Comment: @DemetriPananos min= 1, max= 100